# Is it possible to change extension name TIFW to TFW in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS from the "project-->Save as image" dropdown it is possible to save the current map canvas as Tiff. A world file is also automatically exported. Nice! 
BUT, I use the TIFF+TIFW in another program that only accepts .TFW file. This is the same file, but with a 8.3-type extension. 
Is it possible to get QGIS to export with the TFW extension instead of TIFW?

Comment: "The TFW file extension is used for plain text files that store X and Y pixel size, rotational information, and world coordinates for a map that is stored as a TIFF image in a GIS application". So, TFW files are not raster.

Comment: That is correct. But can I get QGIS to save the file with the .TFW extension instead of .TIFW?

Comment: You need a world file if the tiff raster has not assigned a projection. Are you using this kind of raster in the another program?

Comment: I use the TIF file in another program. This other program looks for a TFW file to define the projection. It does NOT look for TIFW files. So what I do now is manually change the extension from TIFW to TFW. This works, but adds yet another step in the workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manually edit the file extension to be TFW instead of TIFW.  It is a perfectly acceptable standard and QGIS should read it without breaking anything.  The TFW file is just a very simple text file. You can open it with a text editor if you want to see the contents.  If you *really* want, you can have both a TIFW and a TFW in the same folder without upsetting most software.

WLD is another option in some instances (depending on the versatility of your software) and is in fact what QGIS 2.6 outputs if you go `Raster->Projections->Extract Projection`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, manually changing the TIFW extension to TFW is what I do now.  I works well, except that I have to do it for a lot of files. So I was wondering if there was some setting in QGIS that gave me the option to save the world file as TFW directly.

Comment: For fast changing the extension of your files you can use the batch function in an image processing software like IrfanView. In the batch conversion dialog you can use the expression "$N.tfw". More information about this here: http://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#Q14.